# Get items from list inside foreach

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, list, datagridview

I got a class and i'm try to fill the datgaridview as generic list. I got a problem in `dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes`which is a list and i tried to access the list and fill it in the datagridview i coulmdn't succeed. May be both of approach is wrong here...!
Please help me??

When i run, i'm getting a text appears in the grid cell: system colelction generic list.

Added code :

```
  .ForEach(
              Configs =>
                  {  
                      { 
                          datagridview1.Rows.Add(
                              new object[]
                                  {
                                      Configs.Id,
                                      Configs.Description,
                                      Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Id == null ? "" : Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Id.ToString(),
                                      Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Id == null ? "" : Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(1).Id.ToString(),
                                      Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(2).Id == null ? "" : Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(2).Id.ToString(),
                                      Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(3).Id == null ? "" : Configs.Covered.ElementAtOrDefault(3).Id.ToString(),
```

});
                          }
                      });

Comment: What does CoveredLane look like, and what property of it are you try to store?

Comment: @Justin Harvey: Everyhting is a string text, actually i'm deserialaizing a xml file and displaying it in the DGVview.

Comment: How you are binding innerlist (CoveredLanes) with your gridview ?

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar Gupta:I guess, that is my question?? How do i get the innerlist coverlanes to the gridview.

Comment: you wand display as comma separated string or as list of items ?

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar Gupta; I want to take the first, second, thirs and fourth items and put in the cell after description cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, where you have

```
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ToList(),
```

in your first example, try changing to:

```
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAtOrDefault(0) == null ? "" : dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(0).ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAtOrDefault(1) == null ? "" : dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(1).ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAtOrDefault(2) == null ? "" : dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(2).ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAtOrDefault(3) == null ? "" : dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(3).ToString(),
```

Or, for matching on Id

```
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id=="").ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id=="").ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id=="").ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id=="").ToString(),
```

or more general match on id...

```
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString(),
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString(),
```

andd adding a check for no match...

```
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.Any(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")) ? dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First (cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString() : "",
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.Any(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")) ? dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString() : "",
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.Any(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")) ? dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString() : "",
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.Any(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")) ? dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.First(cl=>cl.Id.Contains("")).ToString() : "",
```

Comment: ok, now I understand I think better what you want, see edits above.

Comment: Justin Harvey: What shoiuld i do if there is no id becasue the third and fourth id is empty but in another element it got 4 ids. Thank you

Comment: @ Justin Harvey : I prefer your first method, how can i add empty string if an elemnt is empty??

Comment: I'm sorry, still i got a problem at element 2,3 i.e 3 & 4th value. Argument out of bound exception. One thing i forgot to tell you actually in this list it got only 2 elements but i got 4 colmuns in the dtagarid for this list so i want to add empty string if it's null. Thank you.

Comment: ElementAtOrDefault will return the default if there is no element at the index.  The default for a class (like CoveredLanes) is null, which is being checked, so it should be ok, can you post up the exact code you have now?

Comment: You have not got it quite right, where you have dtuSensorConfigs.CoveredTrafficLanes.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Id == null you actually need dtuSensorConfigs.CoveredTrafficLanes.ElementAtOrDefault(0) == null

Answer (score 1):

You will have to aggregate the values in `dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes` to display in the field. As an example if there are string values in it you could do:

```
string.Join(",", dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ToArray())
```

to generate a comma seperated list.

Or to show the first 4 items then you would create your object like so:

```
new object[]
{
dapuConfigs.Id,         //col0
dapuConfigs.Description, //col1
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(0), //col2
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(1),//col3
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(2), //col4
dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.ElementAt(3),//col5
dapuConfigs.Position.Value, //col6
dapuConfigs.Position.Value,//col7
}
```

And it would be wise to abstract the formatting code away into a formatter object of some sorts.

A more seperated way to approach this would be to hook up to the CellFormatting event and change the way the cell formats its data. This way your representation logic won't bleed into the model as in the snippet i posted.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2249cf0a.aspx

Comment: In your code above you are adding the actual list to the new object. WHen ToString() gets called on that list it will show up as the typename of the list. What you want is the actual ToString representations of the items inside the list and to do that you need to combine them somehow. string.Join is one way of converting an array of objects to a single string representation.

Comment: can you ellaborate? This error usually means when using linq that the compiler cannot resolve the correct overload. This is a bit of a tricky area of linq, but shouldnt really be an issue here. Can you test the string.Join(",", dapuConfigs.CoveredLanes.Where(x => x.Id.Contains("FilterValue1")).ToArray()) on its own?

Comment: I just noticed you want the first 4 items, ill change to that

Comment: What shoiuld i do if there is no id then not fill the cell?? becasue the third and fourth id is empty but in another element it got 4 ids. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("A");
    lst.Add("D1");
    lst.Add("A2");
    lst.Add("A3");

    List<Test> tst = new List<Test>();
    Test t = new Test();
    t.ListValue = lst;
    t.ID = 1;
    tst.Add(t);

    lst = new MyList();
    lst.Add("B");
    lst.Add("B1");
    lst.Add("A2");
    lst.Add("B3");

    t = new Test();
    t.ListValue = lst;
    t.ID = 2;
    tst.Add(t);

    lst = new MyList();
    lst.Add("C");
    lst.Add("B1");
    lst.Add("C2");
    lst.Add("C3");

    t = new Test();
    t.ListValue = lst;
    t.ID = 3;
    tst.Add(t);
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        var lst2 = (from b in tst
                    select new
                    {
                        b.ID,
                        col2 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, b.ListValue.Where(x => x.StartsWith("A")).ToArray()),
                        col3 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, b.ListValue.Where(x => x.StartsWith("B")).ToArray()),
                        col4 = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, b.ListValue.Where(x => x.StartsWith("C")).ToArray())
                    }).ToList();

        GridView1.DataSource = lst2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string ss = ex.Message;
    }

}

public class Test
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public List<string> ListValue { get; set; }
}
```